# Критические секции WinAPI в цикле: проблемы освобождения секции

Tags: c++, c, winapi

Задача следующая: создать n потоков и в каждом из них выводить уникальную строку посимвольно. Операция вывода должна быть атомарной. Вот функция потока:

```
DWORD WINAPI printUniqueString(PVOID args)
{
    ThreadArgs* ta = reinterpret_cast<ThreadArgs*>(args);
    string str = "Thread";
    while (!ta->canClose)
    {
        EnterCriticalSection(&this->section);

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
        {
            cout << str[i];
            Sleep(200);
        }
        cout << ta->number << endl;

        LeaveCriticalSection(&this->section);
        Sleep(200); // без этой строчки не работает
    }
    delete ta;
    return 0;
}
```

Проблема кроется в том, что без использования функции `Sleep` объект критической секции сразу же после освобождения занимается тем же потоком вновь, и другие потоки не могут получить доступ к секции. Полагаю, что эта проблема слишком распространенная, чтобы иметь красивое лаконичное решение. Кто-то имел с ней дело?

Как выкрутиться из этой ситуации, не используя `Sleep`?

Answer (score 1):

Во-первых, критическая секция - объект внутрипроцессорной синхронизации, которая может использоваться только для синхронизации разных потоков внутри одного процесса. В вашем случае все потоки должен создавать один процесс, я исхожу из того, что у Вас это условие выполняется.

Во-вторых, переключение потоков по-таймауту - достаточно медленная операция, которая выполняется редко (относительно, конечно). Поэтому маловероятно, что система будет делать такое переключение как раз между Вашими LeaveCriticalSection и последующим EnterCriticalSection в следующей итерации цикла - этот фрагмент кода выполняется очень быстро, буквально в пару машинных инструкций.

Чтобы подсказать системе, как надо действовать, Вы можете попробовать вызвать WINAPI функцию [BOOL SwitchToThread(VOID)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686352%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) в конце тела цикла перед переходом на следующую итерацию. В принципе, Вашим Sleep(200) Вы делаете то же самое, только дополнительно устанавливаете таймаут в 200 мсек, в течение которого просите систему не возвращать управление в этот поток.

Правда, следует учитывать, что SwitchToThread() - необязательна для системы, она может просто ее проигнорировать, если у нее нет потоков, ожидающих передачи управления.

Вообще, У Вас в данном примере слишком жесткая конкуренция за разделяемый ресурс - и отсюда все проблемы: все потоки на каждые N*200 мсек. обладания критической секцией (где N - количество символов в строке) дают только пару машинных команд (если убрать Sleep, который после LeaveCriticalSection) - считайте миллионные доли секунды (если не миллиардные) другим потокам на возможность захватить секцию. А в принципе критические секции - как раз наоборот - объект синхронизации, который себя оправдывает при низкой конкуренции за ресурс, когда 99% времени ресурс не нужен и только на 1% мы его захватываем и как можно быстрее освобождаем.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ваш способ, увы, так же не работает. Видимо, все-таки, система действительно игнорирует этот вызов. Я сейчас много читал о критических секций и пришёл к мысли, что, скорее всего, такое поведение вызвано рекурсивностью критических секций, однако установка свойства RecursionCount в ноль так же не помогает. Я понимаю, что рекурсивность - не баг, а фича критическох секций, однако условие лабораторной не позволяет использовать другие объекты синхронизации.

Comment: Если Вы под рекурсивностью имеете в виду повторный вход в критическую секцию потока, который уже вошел в эту секцию ранее, то да - это фича критических секций, чего нет у других объектов синхронизации. Но только у Вас в коде нет рекурсивных захватов: у вас всегда чередуются Вход / Выход (на каждую итерацию цикла).

Comment: То есть в данном случае Sleep оправдан? Ведь все равно все решения сводятся к тому, что просто немножко подождать. Даже времени операции вывода символа в консоль достаточно, чтобы разрешить эту проблему (на моем компьютере).

Comment: да, рекурсивность я уже исключил.

Comment: Да, Sleep здесь оправдан тем, что вы снижаете ним конкуренцию за общий ресурс

Comment: Я так понимаю - хотя возможно ошибаюсь (это только моя догадка), что в момент освобождения критической секции при вызове LeaveCriticalSection не происходит перепланирования потоков, в отличие от вызова Sleep или EnterCriticalSection (в случае, когда секция захвачена другим потоком).

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте воспользоваться вызовом

```
std::this_thread::yield();
```

(`thrd_yield()` в чистом C).

Comment: спасибо, но никак не помогло. Я добавил эту строчку сразу поcле LeaveCriticalSection.